# Difference between onTap and onTouchEvent in Android

Tags: android, maps, touch-event

I have an application showing the map and some markers on it.
I use the function `draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)` to put the markers. If you click somewhere on the map a toast appears and shows the address of the location clicked. I implement this with the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)` function. But I want when you click a marker a separate dialog with additional info to show up. In some tutorials they use the `onTap` for this - is there any difference between the `onTap` and the `onTouchEvent` functions? 
And is there any other (better) function in order to make this dialog appear you would recommend me?

How to differentiate a click on the map from a click on a marker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onTouchEvent covers any kind of touch event, that include onTap, onScroll, on Fling, etc

Comment: And is there any way to differentiate a touch on the map from a touch on a marker(drawable)?

Comment: If by marker you mean an overlay perhapds of the itemizedoverlay type then you should check out 
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html

if you do tap on the overlay then it will use it's own onTap method to do what you like, you then return true to say you used the touch input

Answer (score 0):

An `onTap` event is generally a quick down and up motion that is pretty the same as `onClick`. An `onTouch` event covers all types of touch events which can be separated with `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_UP`, `ACTION_MOVE`, etc.

Comment: And is there any way to differentiate a touch on the map from a touch on a marker(drawable)?